# Como criar uma ProgressBar com Python e PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em criar uma *progress bar*, na verdade é em interagir com ela pois criar em si até é fácil:

```
self.progressbar = QProgressBar()
self.progressBar.setRange(0, 10000)
self.progressBar.setValue(0)
```

Com isso ela já aparece. Minha dificuldade é a seguinte:

Tenho uma variável que é a quantidade máxima de arquivos que eu quero copiar, acredito que seria o valor máximo da minha `progressbar`. O valor inicial seria zero. Agora, como faria esse iteração para preencher a `progressbar`, mostrando o percentual?

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber quem é o grande gênio que gosta de dar sinal de negativo sem dizer o que está de errado para podermos melhorar.
Onde está o moderador que nessa hora não ajuda?

Comment: Se você possui `N` arquivos no total e já copiou `n`, a sua porcentagem será `(n/N)*100`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ou apenas setar o valor máximo do range e no setValue aplicar qual é o index atual :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Assim ele mostraria igual o porcentual?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a barra sim, se tiver texto não. No caso de "texto/label" ai concordo contigo, vai ter que ser na "regra de três"

Comment: Caro Cleber, o downvote não é meu, mas quando recebe um não adianta ficar achando que é pessoal, vou dizer o que sua pergunta provavelmente tem de problema: Você não apresentou o código que copia, logo fica difícil orientar. Então quem votou negativo foi uma forma de chamar a atenção dizendo que a pergunta esta vaga, eu me arrisquei em responder, mas muitas vezes isso causa mais trabalho para quem responde do que devia, não estou dizendo que é o seu caso, mas na maioria dos casos sim.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme Nascimento. É isso que me refiro. Para muitos assim como eu que é novo por aqui, precisamos de ajuda ao invés de somente negativar ou criticar. Com isso vou melhorando meus posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer de duas formas, setar o range com a quantidade de arquivos (somente no começo, não precisa ficar dentro da "operação" de copias):

```
self.progressBar.setRange(0, quantidadeDeArquivos)
```

E a cada busca por um novo arquivo copiado dizer em qual valor esta o index:

```
self.progressBar.setValue(indexAtual)
```

Assim não precisará de calcular a porcentagem

A outra forma é justamente calcular a porcentagem, seta o range como 100:

```
self.progressbar = QProgressBar()
self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
```

E no valor aplica o calculo em setValue:

```
self.progressBar.setValue((indexAtual / quantidadeDeArquivos) * 100)
```

Mas realmente isso **não é necessário**, já que você pode controlar o range limite, a não ser que a intenção seja mostrar "no label" em percentual também

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: @CleberNandi por nada :)